# xcode swift 3 FOR ,IF?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Вот такой вот код:

```
for tact in 0...Int(tacts) {
if tact != 1 ||  tact != 3 {
    print(tact)
}
```

}

В результате печатает все такты и 0 и 1 и 2 и 3 и 4 и т.д.
Кто-нибудь знает почему?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас же там дизъюнкция. Когда tact равен 1, он не равен 3. Когда он равен 3, он не равен 1. Всегда что-то выполняется.

Если вы хотели, чтобы 1 и 3 не печаталось, нужно || заменить на &&:

```
for tact in 0...Int(tacts) {
    if tact != 1 &&  tact != 3 {
        print(tact)
    }
}
```